# Stripes appearing on rendered objects?

Tags: rendering, particles

I just started out learning Blender and when I tried to render my images, a pattern of stripes appear on my objects. What causes this?

[image: Stripes can be seen on the cover of the bottle as well as the cream tube]

Just to note I used 1000 sampling in this render since I before I encountered a noise issue.

The image I used in the UV editor is this one:

[image: Images used in UV editor]

As you can see there are no white stripes in the image that I used.

[image: The result after the rendering]

BlendExchange did not work for me so here is [Wetransfer](https://we.tl/t-zmYzzXLf2d)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: render looks fine. Are you looking for this strips in solid view https://imgur.com/gallery/dNCa4I3. I

Comment: Why is your Blend file password protected? To share blendfiles here use [BlendExchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead

Comment: "*Just to note I used 1000 particles in this render*" Where? Why?

Comment: Are you talking about the "bump/normal" stripes on the round models?

Comment: @Timaroberts thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @atek it's not it. I'll try and explain my problem more

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks! will do

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Yes! Those white stripes on the round models.

Comment: > "Just to note I used 1000 particles in this render" Where? Why?

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos, he meant "1000 sampling".. I suppose..

Comment: please share the file :)

Comment: @sanbaldo Yes I meant 1000 sampling, sorry. for some reason the website that someone provided, The blendExchange website does not work for me. Is there some other way to upload the file?

Comment: @Riyad, don't know why Blend Eschange does not work for you, but can use this https://wetransfer.com/ instead for instance. Don't forget to pack the textures in the blend file (as they can be involved in the issue).

Comment: I have a guess but first, Is it only appearing on the pink color?

Comment: @LeoNas I think so, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you sent the real texture.

Your texture is a **png** in a particular case: it is an **index** image.

The *index image* has a short **Color Table**, only 256 colors.

You have a pink gradient using a too limited number of colors.

I'm sending an image showing the problem when I changed the **Color Table**. Note the stripes are only affecting the pink colors.

To solve it, use the original file in **RGB** mode.

You cannot use the **index** file to conver to **RGB**, because you cannot bring back the colors you lost when you converted it to **Index Mode**.

[image: Original Color Table]
[image: Grayscale Color Table]

Extra info:

This particular case was caused by converting from Illustrator to PNG.
Illustrator does not render gradients properly when exported.
It's a good practice using a raster-based program to make gradients.

Comment: I see where you are coming from @LeoNas and I do think indeed that that is the problem. The original picture was made in AI using CMYK color mode, I tried changing the color mode of the file to RGB then exporting the image as PNG but the problem still persists. Here's a link to the original AI file [link](https://we.tl/t-CA18GqQAks). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I got it. Illustrator does not render gradients properly when exported. My idea. Hide de pink gradient shapes, save the file, open it in Photoshop(Media Box, Anti-aliased, 72ppi), make the gradient inside Photoshop.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much!